# Manage substring with empty records

Tags: sql-server

I have two field in a table representing the firstname and lastname, and must put together in a single field in a view. While doing so I must put all in small caps.

```
    SELECT 
    /* NAME*/ COALESCE(UPPER(SUBSTRING(LastName, 1, 1)), '') + COALESCE(LOWER(SUBSTRING(LastName, 2, LEN(LastName)-1)), '') + ' ' + 
    COALESCE(UPPER(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1)), '') + COALESCE(LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 2, LEN(FirstName)-1)), '') AS Name
```

This works fine, but some record has been inserted with one field empty, so the substring generate an error and stop all the queries.

How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(30)= '';
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(30)= 'jhon';   

SELECT CASE WHEN (LEN(@LastName) > 0 AND @LastName IS NOT NULL)
     THEN 
      ISNULL(UPPER(LEFT(@LastName, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@LastName, LEN(@LastName)-1)) + ' ', '')
     ELSE '' END  
   + CASE WHEN (LEN(@FirstName) > 0 AND @FirstName IS NOT NULL)
     THEN 
      ISNULL(UPPER(LEFT(@FirstName, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@FirstName, LEN(@FirstName)-1)), '')
     ELSE '' END    AS Name
```

Comment: Can I put it toghether other fields? And @LastName is only for this example and must be replaced with the field name?
Thank you

Comment: @Fehu Yes this is just to show that you can use `CASE` statement before you use any functions on it. as using LEFT, RIGHT string functions on empty string will cause an error you can use a case statement and do different thing sin different scenarios. Accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
replace(lower(lastname),SUBSTRING(lastName , 1, 1),UPPER(SUBSTRING(lastName , 1, 1))) + ' ' +
replace(lower(firstname),SUBSTRING(firstName , 1, 1),UPPER(SUBSTRING(firstName , 1, 1)))
```